# How can I parse specific info from html source code using Java

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing, web-scraping

I know there is lots of topics for my question but I couldnt find helpful solution for my answer. I could connect to website and read line by line in Java, now here is my problem. I want to parse a specific info from a html page. This page includes 5-day weather forecast. for example the date of forecast tag is like this ;

```
//date of forecast
< th id="ctl00_mpBody_thmGun1" class="arkaTrh">19 April< /th >

//Min weather:
< td id="ctl00_mpBody_thmMin1" class="minS">8< /td>

//Max weather
 < td id="ctl00_mpBody_thmMax1" class="maxS">17< /td>

second day and others tags continue like this,
< th id="ctl00_mpBody_thmGun2" class="arkaTrh">20 April< /th >
.
.
.
```

according these tags, I need to parse 19 April, 17 and 8.

Comment: I forgot to write, I need to make it by using regex :)

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html
/class=\"arkaTrh\">([0-9a-zA-Z ]+)</td>/

Comment: Consider carefully before using regexes to parse HTML. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 4):

FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT USE A REGEX. I don't know how many times this has to be repeated on SO. You'll end up in a world of pain. Use a parser, there are loads available in java. Here are some of them:

[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)

[Dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)

[htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

But there are dozens more. Just Google "html parser java" or "java dom parser" or something. Please.

Comment: yeah I gave up using regex just solve my problem with JSoup.Elements link = doc.select("th[id=ctl00_mpBody_thmGun"+i+"]");

Answer (score 1):

you could craft some regex like this:

```
id="ctl00_mpBody_thmGun1"[^>]*?>(.*?)<
```

But if you want a more robust solution it would be better to sanitize the HTML and select the data with XPath:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net). It was designed for unit testing web pages but you can use it to parse HTML code. You can get your forecast data using something like this:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://url.to.your.data");

//get temperatures
HtmlTableDataCell minTemp = page.getByXPath("//td[@class='minS']").get(0);
HtmlTableDataCell maxTemp = page.getByXPath("//td[@class='maxS']").get(0);
HtmlTableHeaderCell date = page.getByXPath("//th[@class='arkaTrh']").get(0);

System.out.println("Forecast for " + date.asText() + " - Min: " + minTemp.asText() + ", Max: " + maxTemp.asText());
```

Comment: I wrote my answer before you told you need to use regexp. I think HtmlUnit is way easier than using regexp but if you need it so my answer is not for you.